# Alliance and Territory Limit

Tags: tiny-epic-kingdoms

When you have formed an alliance with another player, does the max 2 meeples per territory limit go away (as in 2 meeples of each player and in total 4 meeples can thus occupy any one territory and earn its resources), or does the 2 meeples limit per resource territory still apply regardless of alliances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit stays:

Page 5: Movement:

> At no point may more than two meeples, of any color, be in the same region

No exception is made for alliances.